# Roasting marshmallows on indoors

Tags: marshmallow

Can I use Choice Ethanol Gel Chafing Dish Fuel to cook marshmallows, or do I have to use a certain kind.

Comment: they use them in the marshmallow roaster things...

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended, [sterno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterno) as it is known in the catering business is proven to be poisonous if consumed.  Although the less fortunate have been known to drink the stuff to get drunk (another practice that I don't recommend).
IMO the only purpose of a *sterno* or *Choice Ethanol Gel Chafing Dish Fuel*, as you put it, is for... exactly that: *chafing dishes*.
[image]